# Regex matching lines not containing word EMPTY

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a set of data that I want to extract from. Currently, I only want to extract the lines similar to `2   879-858-35  0x0109037   A   0    # 0131-0 23   24   PLFD   CC` where I am using the regex

```
(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+\w+\s+\d*\s+\#\s+\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(.+)(?!EMPTY)
```

However, I do not want to get the line that contains `EMPTY`. I have tried the regex at [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but it seems like it still matches the line that contains the string `EMPTY`.

Also, is there anyway to shorten the regex? I have tried `(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\d+(.+)(?!EMPTY)` but then it captures `A` (under the header the header `Rev`) all the way the end of the line. Some of my other trial and errors have captured some blank spaces at the end also, I have used `(?!)` once so I'm not sure if I can use it twice, any help on this?

```
CATALYST_TH 1
BACKPLANE A
#Slot Type        Serial #   Rev  Num    Date   XptA XptB Name
  2   879-858-35  0x0109037   A   0    # 0131-0 23   24   PLFD   CC
  6   879-857-01  0x0253bb0   A   0    # 9517-0 15   16   PMM  CC-01
  7   000-000-00  0x0000000  P0   0    # 0000-0 13   14   EMPTY    
  8   000-000-00  0x0000000  P0   0    # 0000-0 11   12   EMPTY    
  9   000-000-00  0x0000000  P0   0    # 0000-0 9    10   EMPTY    
 10   000-000-00  0x0000000  P0   0    # 0000-0 7    8    EMPTY    
 20   000-000-00  0x0000000  P0   0    # 0000-0 37   38   EMPTY    
 21   000-000-00  0x0000000  P0   0    # 0000-0 39   40   EMPTY    
 22   000-000-00  0x0000000  P0   0    # 0000-0 41   42   EMPTY    
 23   000-000-00  0x01a2446  P0   0    # 0000-0 43   44   EMPTY    
  1   949-669-00  0x026a850   B   0    # 0809-0 3    0    HAS (Left HAS LA669-00)
 13   949-668-00  0x200762d   A   0    # 9530-0 0    0    CATALYST HAC
 12   949-667-00  0x026a4ee   D   0    # 0102-0 0    0    DIF
 24   949-669-01  0x2006037   B   0    # 9717-0 4    0    HAS (Right HAS LA669-01)
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `.+` or `.*` after the negative lookahead. And also the worb boundary added before the negative lookahead is a much needed one.

```
(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+\w+\s+\d*\s+\#\s+\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+\b(?!\h+EMPTY\b)\s*(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eB4aD3/2)

Comment: Hmm this does exclude the lines containing `EMPTY` however it doesn't capture the other lines like the ones that have `HAS (Left HAS LA669-00)` at the end.

Comment: where? see the link i attached.

Comment: Yes I mean the one in your link/demo, forget to put that in my comment.

Comment: it matches the lines which has `HAS (Left HAS LA669-00)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiline mode and the following updated regex:

```
/(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+\w+\s+\d*\s+\#\s+\S+\s+(?:\d+\s+){2}((?!.*EMPTY\b).+)$/m
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vA1bS5/2)

The negative lookahead `(?!.*EMPTY\b)` in `((?!.*EMPTY\b).+)` checks if the substring after the previous subpattern is not ending in `EMPTY`.

It is difficult to shorten your regex since there is only 1 repetitive pattern `\d+\s+` that we can shorten as `(?:\d+\s+){2}`.

Comment: Tried your answer as well and it is working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use negative lookahead at the start:

```
^(?!.*EMPTY\s*$)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+\w+\s+\d*\s+\#\s+\S+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(.+)
```

I used the your regex and prepended `^(?!.*EMPTY\s*$)\s+`. The reason is that the negative lookahead will have to be anchored to something or else part of it will be eaten by `.+` and it will be ignored, even though you have `EMPTY` at the end. Here I anchored it to the beginning of the string.